# Transforming a byte array into an array of byte arrays with F#

Tags: array, image, f#

This code is intended to be used with an image manipulation library that I'm working on, and the goal is to take the raw byte[] data from an image, and transform it into a 2D array where each position on the array has a value corresponding to the pixel coordinates of the image.

Comments concerning how to do this faster or more aligned with F# standards, or concerning style and formatting, are very much appreciated. I'm still learning F# so I need all the help I can get.

```
let Transform2D (pArrayWidth:int) (pArray:byte[]) = 
    let tHeight = pArray.Length / pArrayWidth
    let tImageArray = Array.zeroCreate<byte[]> tHeight

    let mutable tStart = 0
    let mutable tFinish = tStart + pArrayWidth - 1        // 0 indexed array

    for tRowIndex in [ 0 .. tHeight ] do
        tImageArray.[tRowIndex] <- pArray.[tStart .. tFinish]
        tStart <- tStart + pArrayWidth
        tFinish <- tFinish + pArrayWidth

    tImageArray
```

Comment: So, the image is a greyscale 8-bit bitmap? (Otherwise, one byte per pixel wouldn't make sense.)

Comment: Ummmmm, actually now that you mentioned that I think I might need to go review that bit of information.

Comment: Does the transformation part seem ok though, even if I need to increase the width that I'm slicing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider whether `byte[][]` is really the best type to represent a bitmap in F#.

On one hand, arrays are inherently mutable and don't work well with pattern matching, so you might want to consider using `list<list<byte>>`, especially if performance is not critical.

On the other hand, a rectangular array of bytes is more accurately modeled as `byte[,]` (2D array), not `byte[][]` (array of arrays, a.k.a. jagged array). Though again, [this is going to be slower than the original option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/468873/41071).

---

```
for tRowIndex in [ 0 .. tHeight ] do
```

This has to be `tHeight - 1`, otherwise your code will fail with an exception.

---

```
let mutable tStart = 0
let mutable tFinish = tStart + pArrayWidth - 1        // 0 indexed array

for tRowIndex in [ 0 .. tHeight ] do
    tImageArray.[tRowIndex] <- pArray.[tStart .. tFinish]
    tStart <- tStart + pArrayWidth
    tFinish <- tFinish + pArrayWidth

tImageArray
```

[You can use sequence expressions to create arrays in a functional way.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233214.aspx) Here, that would look something like:

```
[|
    for tRowIndex in [ 0 .. tHeight - 1 ] do
        let tStart = tRowIndex * pArrayWidth
        let tFinish = tStart + pArrayWidth - 1
        yield pArray.[tStart .. tFinish]
|]
```

In both cases, a very similar syntax (`for` .. `in`) is used, but my version doesn't use any mutable variables and is very similar to [list comprehensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension) in other functional languages.

Comment: I'm actually accustomed to using list comprehensions in python, but I'm trying to adjust to F# from a C# mindset, so it's taking a bit of effort to see problems in a new way. I have a bit of confusion understanding what you mean concerning performance issues with the 2D array vs an array of arrays, are you saying that the byte[][] is fastest, byte[,] is fastest, or the list<list<byte>> is fastest?

Comment: @KortPleco If you know C#, then you should know LINQ, which is also quite similar to list comprehensions (using yet another syntax). And I meant that `byte[][]` is going to be fastest.

Comment: great, thanks for the clarification. This is going to be very speed sensitive, so that's important for me to know. =)